# Connect laptop to home network using wifi-hotspot on iPhone

Tags: networking, ssh, iphone, wireguard

Looking for some guidance/thoughts here.  I'm going on vacation and will be bringing my laptop which runs 21.04.

I use wireguard on my iPhone to connect to my home network whenever I need to access files stored on my NAS, which runs Ubuntu Server 20.04.  Everything works great with the connection between my cell and my home network and I can SSH into my home network from my phone using my NAS' home network IP address.  "ssh [user]@[NAS_IP]".

However, I'm now trying to get my laptop to connect to my home network via the cell's hot spot, but it's not working as I thought it would.  I want to do this because I typically store everything from my laptop to my NAS instead of my laptop's SSD.

So my phone connects to my home network via wireguard and Dynamic DNS, and my laptop connects to my cell via WiFi hot spot.  I can browse the web just fine using this set up, in fact I'm typing this question on said connection.

However, I'm unable to connect to my home network via my laptop using "ssh [user]@[NAS_IP]" as I expected. I've added my laptop's new IP address, issued by my cell, to my NAS' firewall, at first for one specific port, and then again to anywhere.  But when I try to connect, I just get a time out error.

Any tips on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured it out. I needed to set up my laptop as an additional Wireguard client. My original assumption was that my cell would act as an extension of my home network, which is not the case. I've set up Wireguard on my laptop, connect to my cell's hotspot, then start a connection to WG on my laptop. Works as expected. Leaving this here in case someone else comes across the same question.